# Backward induction (Tao Analysis vol. 1).

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Exercise 2.2.6:

Let $n$ be a natural number, and let $P(m)$ be a property pertaining to natural numbers such that whenever $P(m+1)$ is true, then $P(m)$ is also true. Suppose that also $P(n)$ is true. Prove that $\forall (m \le n) \ P(m)$. Hint: induction on $n$.

I don't know what is meant by doing induction on $n$. What's the property $Q(n)$ that I should attempt to prove by induction on $n$? Normally I see backwards induction being proven with the well-ordering property but at this point in the book it's not been mentioned yet. I would appreciate hints greatly.

Comment: See my formal proof at http://www.dcproof.com/BackwardsInduction.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is:

If $P(n)$ is true then $P(m)$ is true for all $m \le n$.

So in the inductive step, you are trying to prove that if $P(n+1)$ is true then $P(l)$ is true for all $l\le n+1$. While what you know by induction is that if $P(n)$ is true then $P(m)$ is true for all $m\le n$.

You can use the property we haven't used about $P$ yet in order to finish the inductive step.

Answer (score 4):

Let $n=1$, then $P(1)$ is true, and hence all $m\leq n$ (I believe Tao uses $\Bbb{N}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$) is true. Now suppose that for some $n\in\Bbb{N}$ if $m\leq n, P(m)$. Now when we consider $n+1$ use our given statement (that $P(n)\Rightarrow P(n-1)$).

Comment: Tao uses $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.