# Proof of the principle of backwards induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I have difficulty in neatly writing down a proof for the following from Terence Tao's *Analysis I*, where $m{+\!+}$ is the [successor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function):

> Let $n$ be a natural number, and let $P(m)$ be a property pertaining to the natural numbers such that whenever $P(m{+\!+})$ is true, then $P(m)$ is true. Suppose that $P(n)$ is also true. Prove that $P(m)$ is true for all natural numbers $m\leq n$; this is know as the *principle of backwards induction*. (Hint: apply induction to the variable $n$.)

First of all, I am unsure about what the base case should look like. For the induction step, I understand that if we suppose inductively that $P(n)$ is true, that then for a natural number $a$ s.t. $a{+\!+}=n$ it holds that $P(a)$ is true, and then for a natural number $b$ s.t. $b{+\!+}=a$ it holds that $P(b)$ is true etc. Hence for all natural numbers $m\leq n$, $P(m)$ is true.

Could anyone please tell me what the base case should look like, and whether there is a neater way of writing down the induction step?

Comment: Seems to me that the hint is a little misleading. The way I would approach this is try to prove that for any $a \leq n$, $P(m)$ is true for all natural numbers $n - a \leq m \leq n$, by induction on $a$.

Comment: What does $a++=n$ mean?

Comment: This question was asked the other day (or at least a very similar question), see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453013/backward-induction-tao-analysis-vol-1/453025#453025).

Comment: I also believe that rbm is reading from Tao's analysis where he uses $++$ to represent the successor when constructing $\Bbb{N}$ from the Peano axioms.

Comment: But `a++` in programming means `b=a; a=a+1; return b;` which is why this usage is a mess.

Comment: @AsafKaragila KennyHegeland is right. That is indeed what it means. Sorry that I did not mention that. So what I mean to say with $n++=a$ is that the successor of $n$ is $a$.

Comment: Using $++$ is by all means a horrible mathematical notation. In particular since $+$ itself is already in the language and is a binary operator. Using $s$ or $S$ is much clearer and common enough, at least in logic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're probably right, however, I did not invent nor introduce this notation. Terence Tao did in his book *Analysis I*, from which this question originates.

Comment: See my formal proof at http://www.dcproof.com/BackwardsInduction.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is to show the statement can be proved on (upward) induction on $n$, as in the hint.

Suppose the statement holds at a specific $n$. The statement of it for $n{+\!+}$ is then:

Suppose $P(n{+\!+})$ is true, then it follows that $P(m)$ holds for all $m \le n{+\!+}.$

From the assumption that $P(n{+\!+}) \implies P(n),$ we arrive at $P(n)$ true, so that from the inductive hypothesis $P(k)$ holds for all $k \le n$. Together with the assumption that $P(n{+\!+})$ holds, we have the desired conclusion of the inductive step, i.e. that $P(m)$ holds for all $m \le n{+\!+}.$

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: One question that came up, what would you say is the base case (did you include that in your answer)?

Comment: @rbm No I didn't since it seems too obvious. It would just say (for $n=1$): Suppose $P(1)$ holds. Then $P(m)$ holds for all $m \le 1$. But there's only one such $m$, namely $1$, so that there is nothing to show for the base case.

Comment: Seriously awesome. I have never seen induction on the thorem itself before and feel like a Philistine. To make sure I grok your proof: You are given that α is true and you are asked to prove β. You proved that 'α=>β' is true. Thay doesn't imply β is true. You need to say that 'α and α=>β imply β is true'. Nitpicking just to confirm that I really understand your proof. Do I have this right?

Answer (score 6):

*Proof:* Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Using induction on $n$, for the base case $n = 0$, we need to show that $P(m)$ is true $\forall\ m\le 0$. But only $0\le 0$ so we just need to show that $P(0)$ is true. Since $P(n)$ is true from the hypothesis, $P(0)$ is true and that completes the base case.

Suppose inductively that the principle if true for $n$, i.e $P$ is such that $P(n)$ is true, and whenever $P(m{+\!+})$ is true, $P(m)$ is true $\forall m\le n$. We have to show the principle is true for $n{+\!+}$ i.e we need to show that $P(m)$ is true $\forall\ m\le n{+\!+}$ given that $P(n{+\!+})$ is true and given that whenever $P(m{+\!+})$ is true, $P(m)$ is true.

Since $P(n{+\!+})$ is true, then $P(n)$ is also true. So we have to show that $P(m)$ is true $m<n$. But from the inductive hypothesis, $P(m)$ is true $\forall$ $m\le n$ and that completes the induction. $\square$

Comment: This is the same as the answer by coffemath and posted two years earlier. How come this is not the accepted answer?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Read dates carefully.

Answer (score 5):

Prove, by ordinary induction on $k$, the statement "if $n-k\geq0$ then $P(n-k)$.  The base case is $P(n)$, and the induction step, going from $k$ to $k+1$, comes from the "backward induction" hypothesis, because increasing $k$ decreases $n-k$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That is a nice way of converting it to an ordinary induction problem. One question that I have; how exactly does the base case work (why would $P(n)$ hold true)?

Comment: @rbm $P(n)$ was one of your assumptions in the question; you wrote "Suppose that $P(n)$ is also true."

Comment: It seems that assuming well-ordering of the naturals, it's quite easy for students to prove variants of standard induction (complete, backward, forward-backward...). But to show that these variants hold using standard induction requires students to modify the proposition to be proved (in your case, it's $n-k \geq 0 \implies P(n-k)$), which students find difficult. Any tips and ideas that students can practise and use to improve this skill?

Comment: This is a nice hack; unfortunately Tao has not introduced subtraction by the time the principle of backwards induction is presented.

Answer (score 4):

Same answer as @coffeemath but made more clear. The statement to be proved is this:

$\forall n\in \textbf{N}, \Bigg (P(n) \implies (\forall m \le n, P(m)) \Bigg )$

which we can rewrite as, taking $R(n) := (\forall m \le n, P(m))$

$\forall n\in \textbf{N}, \Bigg (P(n) \implies R(n) \Bigg )$

Define $Q(n):=(P(n) \implies R(n) )$. We want to show $\forall n\in \textbf{N}, Q(n)$ and we shall use the principle of mathematical induction on $Q(n)$.

Step 1: $Q(0):=(P(0) \implies R(0) )\equiv (P(0) \implies P(0) )$. Thus, Q(0) is true.

Step 2: Assume $Q(n)$ is true.

Step 3: Since $P(n{+\!+})\implies P(n)$ and $P(n) \implies R(n)$, we have $P(n{+\!+}) \implies R(n)$. (syllogism). Now $ (P(n{+\!+}) \implies R(n)) \equiv (P(n{+\!+}) \implies R(n)) \land P(n{+\!+})) \equiv (P(n{+\!+}) \implies R(n{+\!+})) \equiv Q(n{+\!+})$.

Hence $Q(n)$ is true $\forall n$. QED.

Comment: Of all the different answers on the web to this question, I like this one best because it makes clear why Q(n++) is true. The others gloss over this important feature of an inductive proof.